# How to upload and save a file using bottle framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

HTML:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Category:      <input type="text" name="category" />
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload" />
  <input type="submit" value="Start upload" />
</form>
```

View:

```
@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_login():
    category   = request.forms.get('category')
    upload     = request.files.get('upload')
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)
    if ext not in ('png','jpg','jpeg'):
        return 'File extension not allowed.'

    save_path = get_save_path_for_category(category)
    upload.save(save_path) # appends upload.filename automatically
    return 'OK'
```

I'm trying to do this code but it is not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `get_save_path_for_category` is just an example used in the Bottle documentation and not part of the Bottle API. Try setting `save_path` to `/tmp` or something. If that doesn't help: post errors...

Comment: And: The upload.save() method is part of bottle-0.12dev which is not released yet. If you use bottle 0.11 (the latest stable release) then refer to the stable documentation.

Comment: you get this error "raise AttributeError, name
AttributeError: save" ? ..

Comment: No the error is that I'm using bottle 0.11 and it doesn't support upload.save(). I just wrote a normal write file in python and that worked well.

Answer (score 39):

Starting from **bottle-0.12** the **[FileUpload](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html?highlight=fileupload#bottle.FileUpload)** class was implemented with its **upload.save()** functionality.

Here is example for the **Bottle-0.12**:

```
import os
from bottle import route, request, static_file, run

@route('/')
def root():
    return static_file('test.html', root='.')

@route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    category = request.forms.get('category')
    upload = request.files.get('upload')
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)
    if ext not in ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'):
        return "File extension not allowed."

    save_path = "/tmp/{category}".format(category=category)
    if not os.path.exists(save_path):
        os.makedirs(save_path)

    file_path = "{path}/{file}".format(path=save_path, file=upload.filename)
    upload.save(file_path)
    return "File successfully saved to '{0}'.".format(save_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Note: **os.path.splitext()** function gives extension in ".<ext>" format, not "<ext>".

- If you use version previous to **Bottle-0.12**, change:

  ```
  ...
  upload.save(file_path)
  ...
  ```

to:

```
    ...
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as open_file:
        open_file.write(upload.file.read())
    ...
```

- Run server;
- Type "localhost:8080" in your browser.

Comment: `with open(file_path, 'wb') as open_file`, otherwise you get `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` error