# Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file, files saves with no data

Tags: file, python-3.x, bottle

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/test-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="upload" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start upload" />
</form>
```

And I have a function like this:

```
@route("/test-upload")
@post("/test-upload")
def test_upload():
    if request.POST.get("submit"):
        f = request.POST.get("upload")

        upload_path = "uploaded_files/{0}".format(f.filename)
        f.save(upload_path, overwrite=True)
        return "ok"
    return template("test_upload")
```

Which results in the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 2389, in save
     self._copy_file(fp, chunk_size)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 2367, in _copy_file
     read, write, offset = self.file.read, fp.write, self.file.tell()
 ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

If I change to this, I get the same error as above:

```
    f.save("uploaded_files", overwrite=True)
```

If I use either of these:

```
        with open(upload_path, 'w') as open_file:
             open_file.write(f.file.read())
```

or

```
        with open(upload_path, 'wb') as open_file:
            open_file.write(f.file.read())
```

I this error:

```
open_file.write(f.file.read())
 ValueError: read of closed file
```

What's confusing is that something does save to the file system, with the proper extension (I've tested jpeg and pdf), there is no data in any of the files. I just don't see what, if anything, I am doing wrong with either version. I'm looking to upload a file with data.

I'm using Python3.4 with bottle.

some things I've looked at: [How to upload and save a file using bottle framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050064/how-to-upload-and-save-a-file-using-bottle-framework)

and: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#file-uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
f = request.files.get('upload') # .files, not .post
f.save(upload_path)
```

Edit:
[#567 In python 3.4 multipart file upload breaks due to change in cgi.FieldStorage](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/567)

but it should be fixed.
can you try updating your bottle version to the last one?